# Caramel Apple cocktail garnish

Tags: cocktails, apples, caramel

I am a bartender who has little experience using caramel.  I want to use caramel as a garnish by dipping dehydrated apple slices in it.  How do I create a "dripping effect" on the dehydrated apple slice?  I need it to look "drippy", but also need it to be hardened.  Also, is it possible to prepare the apples in advance, or do I need to do each one when making the drink?  This is for a cocktail competition, so the garnish has to be on point.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Define "dripping effect", please...

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Visit your competitors and get us a picture of what you're looking for.

Comment: To help you get a start, you probably want a fairly hard (or at least solid) caramel, and to melt it for dipping. You'll need to experiment with how hot, and how you cool it.

Comment: Are you making the caramel from sugar yourself? Do you have a sugar thermometer or a normal thermometer that would measure up to 200C?

Answer (score 1):

Leave the caramel to cool further, as the thickness should increase as it cools.  Once it is at the required thickness, you can drip ropes of caramel on to the apple to make a drip effect.  Alternatively have a separate thicker caramel to make the drip effect.

This is can be seen as a sugar work/pulled sugar technique.  Also it woudl be recommended to do this in advance to allow the caramel to fully harden.  Note: temperature and humidity can affect the caramel.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are making the caramel by heating sugar. This is [a good place to start reading up on sugar temperatures](https://www.craftybaking.com/howto/candy-sugar-syrup-temperature-chart)

Soft-crack and hard-crack are likely to be where you want to experiment.